# Closing bootstrap modal from asp.net code-behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I found this answer, but get the following error:

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Closepopup() {
        debugger;
        $('#myModal').modal('close');
    }
</script>
```

code-behind:

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "Close Modal Popup", "Closepopup();", True)
```

error:

Unhandled exception at line 6, column 13594 in http://localhost:1230/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'close'

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: [Bootstrap modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods) do not recognize the "close" method. Try "hide" instead.

Answer (score 2):

`modal('toggle')` instead of `modal(toggle)`

```
$(function () {
   $('#modal').modal('toggle');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` instead of `$('#myModal').modal('close');`

source: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events